# Windows 10 bash: nvm: command not found

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, nvm, nvm-windows

I am trying to set up windows 10 so that I can be able to run multiple versions of node.  I heard about nvm and downloaded it successfully.  When I typed 'nvm' or 'nvm -v', I get the following error, **bash: nvm: command not found**.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows and followed all instructions?

Comment: That was the problem.  After reading, I realized I needed to start powershell as an Admin.  Thank you!